# Updating Stack Exchange avatar?

Tags: support, profile-picture, gravatar

I cannot for the life of me figure out where in the account settings you update your account avatar... Any suggestions?

I don't think I used Gravatar as I could not find an account based on my emails.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your profile.

Click on the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab.

Upload a different picture.

Save.

Done.

Comment: Dont know how I missed that... I have been searching for 15 minutes now......